# awk: How to select multiple substrings from fixed length file?

Tags: awk

I have searched and searched but haven't really found an answer to this.
The idea is that I have a dat file from which some of the data fields are needed.

Example data (test.dat)

```
50DI 20170510144200Mike   Tester       BL0004992000US
50ELI20170509145200Roy    Developer    BL0003400020MX
```

So in the case I would like to have the second data field starting from position 3 (DI or ELI) with lenght of three I would do this:

```
awk '{print substr($0,3,3)}' test.dat
```

But I can't figure out how to get multiple data fields from the original dat file. The best I've come up with is this (edited as I copied older version).

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1}; do
    a=$(awk '{print substr($0,0,2)}' test.txt)
    b=$(awk '{print substr($0,20,7)}' test.txt)
    echo $a, $b
done
```

which results as

```
50 50, Mike Roy
```

instead of

```
50, Mike
50, Roy
```

The example is a bit basic the idea remains the same: how do I get multiple substrings with awk? (Disclaimer: I'm not married to awk, I just want to get better with it. Any other solutions are highly appreciated too!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `awk`, assuming you really want fixed widths:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 17 7' -v OFS=', ' '{ print $1, $3 }' test.dat
```

With `bash`:

```
while read -r line; do
    printf '%s, %s\n' "${line:0:2}" "${line:19:7}"
done <test.dat
```

With a somewhat modern `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(..\).\{17\}\(.\{7\}\).*/\1, \2/' test.dat
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join ", ", unpack "A2x17A7"' test.dat
```

Output, for any of the above:

```
50, Mike
50, Roy
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The source is unfortunately fixed lenght so gotta live with that.

Answer (score 1):

How about `cut`?

```
cut -c1-2,20-26 --output-delimiter ', ' test.dat
50, Mike
50, Roy
```

Answer (score 0):

Short ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -En 's/^(.{2}).{17}(\S+).*/\1, \2/gp' test.dat
```

The output:

```
50, Mike
50, Roy
```